# Maven Shade Plugin causes duplicate jars on classpath when running integration tests

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, maven-shade-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have a project which includes the S3 dependency from [AWS's Java v2 SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2) and builds a shaded jar. I am hitting [this problem](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/953) when running my integration tests from the terminal. The problem is that the interceptors are added twice because the classpath contains two jars with the S3 jar: once in my shaded jar and once from the local .m2 repository. Unfortunately I don't have any control of the code that contains this issue so I need to find a workaround until the issue is fixed.

I have replicated the problem with the following pom and test class:

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.stu</groupId>
    <artifactId>duplicate-jars-classpath</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <aws.sdk.version>2.5.62</aws.sdk.version>
        <junit.version>5.4.2</junit.version>
        <maven.failsafe.plugin.version>2.22.0</maven.failsafe.plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
                <version>${aws.sdk.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
                <version>${junit.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                <version>${junit.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.failsafe.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>run-tests</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**Test class** - src/test/java/com/stu/S3DuplicateJarTest.java

```
package com.stu;

import java.util.Collections;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import software.amazon.awssdk.core.interceptor.ClasspathInterceptorChainFactory;

public class S3DuplicateJarTest {

    @Test
    void check_for_duplicate_jars() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("********** AWS execution interceptors:");
        Collections.list(
                new ClasspathInterceptorChainFactory().getClass().getClassLoader()
                        .getResources("software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/execution.interceptors")
        ).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

If I run the tests in my IDE then this is the output:

```
********** AWS execution interceptors:
jar:file:/Users/<name>/.m2/repository/software/amazon/awssdk/s3/2.5.48/s3-2.5.48.jar!/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/execution.interceptors
```

From the terminal this is the output when running `mvn clean verify`:

```
[INFO] Running com.stu.S3DuplicateJarTest
********** AWS execution interceptors:
jar:file:/Users/<name>/Development/duplicate-jars-classpath/target/duplicate-jars-classpath-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/execution.interceptors
jar:file:/Users/<name>/.m2/repository/software/amazon/awssdk/s3/2.5.62/s3-2.5.62.jar!/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/execution.interceptors
```

As you can see the terminal has found two resources matching the path.

Is there anything I can do to avoid this? Is there something wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to your maven configuration, `shade` plugin packs all dependencies into a single jar file.

Your `failsafe` plugin runs tests using class path from both the project dependencies (`.m2/...`) and that single jar file, hence the duplicated resources.

This seems to be only happening when using `failsafe` in command line, though. And it's fairly easy to get around, you can simply tell `failsafe` to not load that dependency. (It'll be available in that single jar file anyway)

```xml
  <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${maven.failsafe.plugin.version}</version>
      <configuration>
          <includes>
              <include>**/*Test.java</include>
          </includes>
          <classpathDependencyExcludes>
              <classpathDependencyExcludes>software.amazon.awssdk:s3</classpathDependencyExcludes>
          </classpathDependencyExcludes>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
          <execution>
              <id>run-tests</id>
              <phase>integration-test</phase>
              <goals>
                  <goal>integration-test</goal>
                  <goal>verify</goal>
              </goals>
          </execution>
      </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you! I went even further and added a scope exclusion of `runtime` to exclude all compile and runtime dependencies. As I have a shaded jar with all dependencies this is perfectly acceptable. This is the configuration `<classpathDependencyScopeExclude>runtime</classpathDependencyScopeExclude>` as per https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/configuring-classpath.html

Comment: Be aware that if you use this configuration, IntelliJ also excludes the runtime-scoped dependencies. However, IntelliJ does not run the test on the shaded JAR, so now you miss all runtime dependencies, and IntelliJ will fail with NoClassDefFoundError.