# Failed to load ApplicationContext in tests when maven-shade-plugin is used

Tags: java, spring, maven, integration-testing, maven-shade-plugin

I have this test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:some-context-test.xml")
@DirtiesContext
public class SomeClassIT {
  ...
  @Test
  public void someTestMethod() {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

which runs with no problems when triggered from IntelliJ IDEA, but fails with the error

```
[ERROR] someTestMethod(x.y.z.SomeClassIT)  Time elapsed: 0.001 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/db.xml]: Invocation of init method
 failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: AttributeConverter class [class x.y.z.SomeConverter]
 registered multiple times
Caused by: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: AttributeConverter class [class x.y.z.SomeConverter] registered
 multiple times
```

when executed via maven

```
mvn verify -DskipITs=false
```

But if I remove maven-shade-plugin config from pom.xml (the project is using it), then test executes with success even via maven.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56589859/2806801. The parameter `classpathDependencyScopeExclude` of maven-failsafe-plugin:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>[...]</version>
        <configuration>
          <classpathDependencyScopeExclude>runtime</classpathDependencyScopeExclude>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

DETAILS

Because of maven-shade-plugin the `META-INF/db.xml` (imported by `some-context-test.xml`) was loaded twice:

1. jar:file:/C:/Users/.../project/module1/target/module1-v.1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/META-INF/db.xml
2. jar:file:/C:/Users/.../.m2/repository/.../project/module2/1.0.0/module2-1.0.0.jar!/META-INF/db.xml

After I set parameter `classpathDependencyScopeExclude` to `runtime` the `META-INF/db.xml` was loaded only from

1. jar:file:/C:/Users/.../project/module1/target/module1-v.1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/META-INF/db.xml